# Interface-level isolation

Tags: c#, architecture, console

In my console application I have the class that incapsulates performing  long-continued work and I need show the progress to user.
Do I need put into object of this class a delegate for interaction with console or to write from class right to screen is ok from the standpoint of application structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not write to the screen from within that class. I would go with your first suggestion to use events for this - not simply delegates.

You could have an event named `OnProgressUpdate` which informs the main thread about your current progress state.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer creating an interface `IProgressToken` which allows setting the current progress, and supplying that to the calculation method.

You can then create an implementation of that interface that writes the progress to the console directly, or every so often, or that updates a progress bar on a form, sending an sms, without having to change the class that performs the calculation.

```
interface IProgressToken
{
    void SetProgress(float percentage);
}

class MyProgressToken : IProgressToken
{
    void SetProgress(float percentage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("current progress: " + percentage + "%");
    }
}

// The long running method
ResultType MyCalculationMethod(InputType input, IProgressToken progressToken)
{
    progressToken.SetProgress(0);
    ...
    progressToken.SetProgress(100);
}
```

Comment: That would work for a console application, but on a desktop/winrt application you'd have to make sure that the `IProgressThingie` object runs on the UI thread. Although your suggestion is good for a console app (which is what SerG is looking for), I'd go with events for other types of applications.

Comment: Events also end up on the thread they occur, you still need to look at `Control.InvokeRequired` in that case. Not that events are a bad idea, though!

Comment: Really? I wasn't aware of that. I thought that the callback would run on the thread that first registered the event (aka the UI thread). I seem to have made a wrong assumption.

Comment: Although, now that I think about it, it makes perfect sense for the event to be raised and handled on the same thread...

Comment: Still, using events is a clean solution. I think I've become too enterprisey creating custom objects for everything :P

Comment: Haha I tend to do that too often as well :P